# How to include a store variable in the definition of a custom variable

Tags: email, email-templates

I am trying to customize an email template ( new password ) and for this I have defined a custom variable 'footer-email' like this :

```
<p> Thank you for shopping at {{config path="general/store_information/name"}} </p>
```

I include the variable in the email template with :

```
{{customVar code=footer-email}}
```

The problem is that the store name does not appear in the resulting email . However, if I include `{{config path="general/store_information/name"}}` directly in the template ( instead of the custom variable) , it displays properly.

Is it a scope issue? Is it possible to use 'variable within variables' ?

Note that I run CE 1.9 and have only one store.

Thanks in advance for the help.